# How to count a specific character in an array and also call the function?

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, char

I am trying to make a program to count a specific character in an array. I got the program working how I think it should be working, however it was all in my main function and I wanted to break it out of there but I seem to be having an issue with doing so. My code when it was all in main was:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void)
{
   char array[100];
   int i = 0;
   int a_counter = 0;
   printf("Enter an array: \n");
   scanf("%[^\n], array);
   printf("Array is: %s\n", array);
   for( i = 0; array[i] != '\0'; i++)
   {
      if (array[i] == 'A')
        a_counter++;
   }
   printf("Number of A's: %d\n, a_counter);
```

}

In the code above, if I enter AAABCDEF, the result would tell me that there are 3 A's.

Now, I want to get this out of main and also not limit the character to only being an 'A'. I wanted to to count whatever character I set the function call with. My attempt to do so was this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void)
{
   char array[100];
   printf("Enter an array: \n");
   scanf("%[^\n], array);
   printf("Array is: %s\n", array);

   countletter(array, 'A');
   countletter(array, 'L');            //I want to call function and add 
                                       //whatever letter I felt like it
   return 0;      
 }

 void countletter(char(array), char x)
 {
   int i = 0;
   int count = 0;
   for (i = 0; array[&i] != '\0'; i++)
      if(array[&i] == x)
         count++;
    printf("Number of %c's: %d\n", x, count);
  }
```

so if I called the countletter function, I wanted it to count the specific letter I sent it to count but my outputs were not even close. My outputs seemed to always be zero, and if I entered a specific array, it would put me in an infinite input mode. It seems that I am still confused on pointers and passing and calling functions.

Comment: 1) `char(array)` --> `char array[]` 2) `array[&i]` --> `array[i]` 3) put `void countletter(char array[], char x);` before `main`. 4) `"%[^\n],` --> `"%[^\n]",`

Answer (score 2):

The function you have written is wrong

```
void countletter(char *array, char x)
{
  int i = 0;
  int count = 0;
  for (i = 0; array[i] != '\0'; i++)
     if(array[i] == x)
       count++;
  printf("Number of %c's: %d\n", x, count);
}
```

Also before main, you have to declare the function

```
void countletter(char *array, char x);
```

Answer (score 2):

Instead of defining

```
void countletter(char(array), char x)
 {
   int i = 0;
   int count = 0;
   for (i = 0; array[&i] != '\0'; i++)
      if(array[&i] == x)
         count++;
    printf("Number of %c's: %d\n", x, count);
  }
```

you should define:

```
void countletter(char array[], char x) // OR void countletter(char* array, char x)
 {
   int i = 0;
   int count = 0;
   for (i = 0; array[i] != '\0'; i++)
      if(array[i] == x)
         count++;
    printf("Number of %c's: %d\n", x, count);
  }
```

Moreover its a good practice to always pass size with an array or string. So probably below is the better function prototype.

```
void countletter(char array[], int size, char x)
```

Comment: Thank you! this is exactly where my confusion was. It is working perfect. However, I had one more question in hopes of not having to make a whole new question...My question is, is there a way using the toupper() function that I could take in input that was lowercase 'a', and 'l', and still count them along with still counting the capital version?

Comment: I didn't get your doubt. Can you please explain properly using an example?

Comment: ok, so if I had entered AabcdlL as an input. I want it to count both the capital and lowercase letters of 'a/A' and 'l/L'. The output would say there are 2 A's and 2 L's if that clears up any confusion. I assumed I could just add the 'toupper' function somewhere but I have had no luck.

Comment: Okay. So basically you want to make case insensitive count of char provided in the countletter() function parameter 'x'. In that case replace the conditional block <if(array[i] == x)> inside the loop with <if(toupper(array[i]) == toupper(x))>

Answer (score 2):

There are two errors int he code:

```
void countletter(char(array), char x)
```

and

```
 for (i = 0; array[&i] != '\0'; i++)
  if(array[&i] == x)
```

The correct lines are:

```
void countletter(char* array, size_t size, char x)
```

and

```
 for (i = 0; (i < size) && (array[i] != '\0'); i++)
  if(array[i] == x)
```

You have to pass the entire array (by passing pointer to its first element in my example) and you have to work as usual (exactly as you did in the first monolithic version).

You must also pass the array size and take it into account when working with the array.

Answer (score 0):

I would personally prefer this syntax for dealing with pointers.

```
void countLetter(char *array, char x) {...}
```

And for iterating through the array

```
for(i=0; *(array+i) != '\0'; i++)
```

Similarly for comparing

```
if(*(array+i) == x)
```

Internally, `array[i]` gets converted in `*(array+i)`, so you can choose whatever you want.
The problem with your code is your method

```
countletter(char(array), char x)
```

This method is expecting two characters as parameters, where as you are passing a pointer and a character.
Second one is

```
array[&i]
```

For accessing ith element of an array, you should use something like `array[i]`.